# ¿Cómo pasar mi base de datos de firestore a tensorflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, tensorflow

Soy nueva utilizando Python y en inteligencia artificial, pero quiero construir una red neuronal que con una base de datos de canciones pueda aprender distintas partituras, pero quisiera saber... ¿Cómo puedo cargar los datos de mi BD de firestore?
He visto que que tensorflow tiene la función load_data, pero no sé cómo utilizarla para agregar una bd de firestore. También ví en internet que con la función getDummie puedo pasar mis datos categóricos a númericos, pero no sé como pasar mi bd....

Esta es mi base de datos....

[image: e]

Perdón si mi pregunta parece tonta, pero soy completamente una novata con la IA, el uso de python y tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos maneras, una es guardándola en tu computadora después de exportarlas a un bucket de google cloud storage

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Y luego descargas el contenido del bucket.

Esta primera aproximación no la consideraría tan útil para mi. La segunda manera es utilizando el módulo `firestore` de las bibliotecas de `google` para python.

Por ejemplo.

```
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()

colection_ref = db.collection(u'nombre_de_coleccion')

for doc in colection_ref.stream():
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Hasta donde recuerdo no es posible descargar todas las colecciones de una sóla vez (o cómo en México se dice, "De un putazo") sino que tendrías que tener una lista con el nombre de las colecciones e ir iterando sobre esa lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
colecciones = ['col1','col2','coln']
for coleccion in colecciones:
    col_ref = db.collection(coleccion)

...
resto del código.
```

Para instalar este modulo deberás hacerlo con

```
pip install google-cloud-firestore
```

El ejemplo es tomado de la [documentación](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) oficial

Sólo que como comentario. Para poder hacer uso de este módulo y tu base de datos deberás autenticarte con credenciales del proyecto de firebase.